# How to use Triple Exponential Smoothing to forecast into future?

Tags: python, pandas, forecast

I want to use Holt-Winters method to forecast into the future. To predict the current values for `IdCount` with Exponential Smoothing I used this code:

```
df['TES_mul'] = ExponentialSmoothing(df['IdCount'],trend='add',seasonal='add',seasonal_periods=9).fit().fittedvalues
```

This works out fine. Now, I want to "use" Triple Exponential Smmothing to predict future values.

What do I have to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Triple Exponential Smoothing" is also known as the Hold-Winters method. Please take a look the documentation of:
`from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing`

[for more details see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Triple_exponential_smoothing_(Holt_Winters))